# Для онлайн-игры (стрелялки, бродилки) что важно?

Tags: c#, c++, linux, разработка-игр

Для онлайн-игры (стрелялки, бродилки) что важно?

ping, fps, расположение сервера... что ещё?
перечислите....

есть тут разработчики которые делают игры
или те кто играет в игры. может кто подсказать?

Comment: Навязчивый пост однотипных вопросов низкого качества, см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1130765/213987